# Script has disappeared and cannot be referenced

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Unity Compiler Error:** `MissingRefernceException: The object of type 'WeaponManager' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null of you should not destroy the object.`

I tried making it static and even tried using the **DontDestroyOnLoad** method so that my *WeaponManager* script wouldn't disappear.

I can't refer to it because the object keeps disappearing.

Comment: If you don't provide code we can't help you with that problem. Unity is telling you that the instance of WeaponManager that you are trying to use has been destroyed. Please provide more information about what you actually do with that GameObject as well as some useful code.

Comment: If you're forcefully destroying the object using Destroy function, it will be destroyed regardless of DontDestroyOnLoad.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.